# .NET Type initialisation exception after IIS recycle event

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis-7.5, application-pool

Using .NET 3.5 C#, I have a WCF web service serving mobile clients. The clients frequently use the service to send data to the server and receive updates. The service in deployed in IIS 7.5 and is configured to recycle every morning at 0600 hrs. The recycle usually works seemlessly and the clients continue to use the service as usual. However there has been a couple of incidents where the recycle results in the application getting into a funny state and I can see the log full of type initialisation errors as below. It is almost like something happens during the overlapped recyling where it has not successfully unloaded the DLLs:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.set_Item(TKey key, TValue value)
   at Docobo.Keswick.DbAccess.TableData.DataClasses.GetInfo(Type type)
```

The DataClasses is an internal static class used by IQToolkit to lookup database table names:

```
internal static class DataClasses
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, DataClassInfo> classInfos = new Dictionary<Type, DataClassInfo>();

    public static DataClassInfo GetInfo(Type type)
    {
        DataClassInfo info;
        if (!classInfos.TryGetValue(type, out info))
        {
            // This is not thread-safe, but that's fine.
            // If this class is generated more than once it doesn't matter.
            info = new DataClassInfo(type);
            classInfos[type] = info;
        }
        return info;
    }
}
```

Manually recycling the application pool fixed the problem.
From the stacktrace it seems that the static readonly field **classInfos** may be NULL but I don't know how that can be?

Comment: Any chance `type` can be null?

Comment: No. I do not think so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception occurs inside the dictionary, as you can see from the stack trace:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert
```

Pretty much the only reason it can happen is if you access the dictionary concurrently. Try wrapping it inside a `lock` statement.

I'm guessing the reason why it occurs during a recycle is follows. Reading the dictionary is probably thread-safe, so the chances of an exception are higher during startup. And during a recycle, multiple simultaneous client requests may be paused to wait until the application restarts. So after the application restarts, multiple write attempts happen simultaneously.